# How can I make execution pause until new form is closed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a Win Forms application to learn more since I don't have much experience with it. In my program, in the main form, I have a button. Clicking it launches another form. The code is as follows:

```
 private void btn_AddCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                form_NewCat NewCatForm = new form_NewCat();
                NewCatForm.Show();
            }));

            MessageBox.Show("Oops!");            
        }
```

The problem is, when the new form is launched, I want execution of the code behind the main form to pause at that point until the new form is closed. As an example, in the above code, I do not want 'Oops!' to get printed until the new form is closed. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to invoke when you are in the UI thread. And you are in the UI thread in a button-click eventhandler.

```
private void btn_AddCat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form_NewCat NewCatForm = new form_NewCat();
    var dialogResult = NewCatForm.ShowDialog();
    MessageBox.Show("Oops!");            
}
```

You can check the dialogResult for OK, Cancel, Yes, No, etc if your form_NewCat sets this.DialogResult to any value before closing. This is the usual way to signal how the user exited the form/dialog.

Comment: I changed the event handler to exactly what u showed. The new form has a cancel button. The event handler for the cancel button executes this.Close(). However, when I hit the cancel button, the form disappears and then reappears again. Hitting cancel again closes the form. Why is that so? My new form is being displayed twice.

Comment: @xbonez, strange, are you sure you don't have any other code that shows the form? Like in the constructor?

Comment: I was in situation where i can't use ShowDialog(), I added event to form that i want to open and execute rest of the code on closeing `Form frm = new frmScreenCapture(); frm.FormClosed += frm_FormClosed; frm.Show();`

Answer (score 27):

Change the line

```
NewCatForm.Show();
```

to

```
NewCatForm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply change Show to ShowDialog; this also let's you get a return value to indicate whether the form considered itself exiting with a specific status (ok, cancel, etc).

Answer (score 6):

You want a modal dialog and I think you need `NewCatForm.ShowDialog();`